# python script that will filter data from file

Tags: python, json

I am writing a script for scrap data from file (any format like csv,text,json,html etc.) and match list with another file and then replace that particular string from another file ,  each file contain same data and i would like to use regular expression because i want to scrap data after %%string%% and then store string in to the list 
format of file

file1.txt

```
{ 
 "alias": "%%demo%%",
 "demo": "%%demo%%",
 "dns_domain": "googlr.com",
 "max_physical_memory": "%%maxmemory%%",
 "dataset_uuid": "%%DS_UUID%%",
 "nics": [
 {
  "nic_tag": "stub0",
  "ip": "%%ip%%",
  "netmask": "255.255.240.0",
  "primary": "1"
   }
 ]
 }
```

I want to get all of the string  in to the list between %%____%% sign

Python Code

```
import sys
import re
list = []
list1 = []
i = 0
for n in sys.argv[1:]:
#list = []
#list1 = []
print n
input1 = open(n, "w")
#print input1
output = open(n,"r")
for line1 in output:
s = line1.split("=",1)[1:2]
for m in s:
    list1.append(m.strip())
for line in input1:
    a = re.findall(r"%%([^%^\n]+)%%", line)
for val in a:
    list.append(val)
    stext = list[i:0]
        rtext = list1[i:0]
    input1.write(line.replace(val, rtext))  
i += 1
input1.close()
output.close()
```

print list and list2 , list2 having values from file2.txt

file2.txt

```
demo=somehost
demo=somehost2
maxmemory=1025
DS_UUID = 454s5da5d4a
ip=127.0.0.1
```

i want to replace in file1 from file2 , please check my code and let me know how can we do it

Comment: Can you clarify how the input files look like and how the output should look like?

Comment: Can you please add an example to your question?

Comment: @AtulJain `ip` shouldn't be in output?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to all for your time, finally i achive what i want and my code is below

```
import sys
import re

list2 = []

file1 = 'file1.json'
file2 = 'test-var.txt'
output = open(file2, "r")
for line1 in output:
    s = line1.split("=",1)[1:2]
    for m in s:
    list2.append(m)
input1 = open(file1, "r")
list1 = []
txt = ''
for line in input1:
   a = re.findall(r"%%([^%^\n]+)%%",line)
   a = ''.join(a)
   if a =='':
      txt = txt + line
      continue
   if any(a in s for s in list1):
      val = '%%'+a+"1"+'%%'
      line = line.replace('%%'+a+'%%', val)
      a = a + "1"
      txt = txt + line
      list1.append(a)
for i in range(len(list1)):
    string1 = '%%'+''.join(list1[i])+'%%'
    string2 = ''.join(list2[i])
     txt = txt.replace(string1,string2)
input1.close
output.close()
output = open(file1, "w")
print txt
output.write(txt)
output.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to find data inside well-known markers using regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r"%%([^%^\n]+)%%", "hello %%there%% how\n are %%you%%")
['there', 'you']
```

From your updated example, you can extend the list instead of adding sublists

```
import fileinput
import re
array = []
for line in fileinput.input():
    array.extend(re.findall(r"%%([^%^\n]+)%%", line))
print array
fileinput.close()
```

Comment: If you know the file name and the file size is fairly modest (a few 100 meg), then `scraped = re.findall(r"%%([^%^\n]+)%%", open("somefile.txt").read())`.

Comment: i got that, now i want to replace  list value with define in another list which is stored in another file

Comment: @AtulJain - sounds great. Go for it.

Comment: #tdelney , will you please check my updated question, i am not getting exact output

Comment: Sorry, but you've dramatically changed the scope of the question. You could parse the file2.txt into a dict, use `re.sub` to change things of the form `"%%something%%"` into `{something}` and then use `string.vformat` to do the substitution. But I'm not doing the work!